# How do I opt out of this ubisoft connect thing?

Tags: nintendo-switch, ubisoft-connect, immortals-fenyx-rising

I got Immortals Fenyx Rising after hearing it was similar to Breath of the Wild, because I've been craving more BotW but have run out of BotW. But every time I try to start the game, it pops up a modal window with the only option being to connect to a ubisoft account. I do not want to make a ubisoft account. (This isn't even an online game, why do I need to have an account?)

How do I opt out of creating a ubisoft account without having to go turn on airplane mode each time I want to play it?

Comment: Could the downvoter please let me know what I did wrong, so that I can fix it, or at least not do it in the future?

Comment: I wasn't the person with the downvote, but I'd suggest removing the acronyms or fully explaining them. I don't know what you mean by "botw" so it's making your question only partially understandable.

Comment: @Sorean Is that better?

Comment: Doesn't seem like it's possible without airplane mode. It looks like they patched the game to force-keep that login screen open. Read the Reddit thread here: https://www.reddit.com/r/NintendoSwitch/comments/k7oxep/immortals_fenyx_rising_is_there_a_way_to_skip/